# Any solution for a video encoder on WP8

Tags: video-encoding, windows-phone-8

Any solution for a video encoder on WP8 ? I have custom camera frames and need to record video from them. But I can't find any video encoder for WP8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no API for your question. If you want to do it, the only way is to capture each frame using interval and build your own encoder to encode them. Even with that idea, there is no sound.